# Converting a text file content from 'str' to 'int' in Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I am writing a code in which first I am creating a text file and then entering data to it, but the problem is, data which is to be entered is an integer and I don't know how to it, what I am doing I am first giving input in 'str' form and then I don't know how to convert it into integer but I am failed there also. I also want to know that, can we sort the integers inside that file, here is my code:

```
f = open("o.txt","w+")
n = 3
for a in range(n):
    f.write(a)
f.close()
```

and I am getting an error:

```
 write() argument must be str, not int
```

ok then we can give str but how can we convert it into int and sort the whole file.

Question: I want to write it with an integer(if possible or we convert it later) and sort the file?

Comment: You can only write string in a text file.
Question: I want to write it with an integer -> not possible you convert it later

Comment: then can we convert it later?

Answer (score 1):

When you read from the file, you will have to make sure that each line you read is an int, use int().

If you change you code to:

```
f = open("o.txt", "w+")
n = 3
for a in range(n):
    f.write(str(a))
f.close()
```

it will run, but file will look like this:

```
012
```

That will make it impossible to distinguish between each integer. I am assuming that you want to put a bunch of integers into a file and then, separately, sort that file. You should add a newline character to each write.

```
f = open("o.txt", "w+")
n = 3
for a in range(n):
    f.write(str(a) + "\n")
f.close()
```

The new file will look like this:

```
0
1
2
```

and you will be able to read it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to learn about the `format` method of the string type sooner rather than later, at least in its simplest form:

```
f.write( "{}\n".format(a) )
```

will work pretty much whatever `a` might be.